# Generating random dataset fitting some conditions with R

Tags: r, random, dataset

I want to generate a dataset that fits some conditions to simulate the behaviour of some statistical facts in regression models.

To start with, I want a dataset compounded by a single dependent variable Y and three independent variables x1,x2,x3. I need the dataset to be larger than 40 rows (n>40) and I need x1,x2 to be linearly dependent.

I have been reading R documentation to generate random data like `rnorm` or `sample` functions, but I dont end up with anything useful.

How could I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by saying that Y is dependent? What should it depend on and in what way? Also, you say that x1, x2, and x3 are independent and then "I need x1,x2 to be linearly dependent".

Comment: In regression analysis, the dependent variable is denoted "Y" and the independent or explanatory variables are denoted by "X".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own by using `runif` as,

```
X1 <- runif(100,1,50) # 100 random numbers between 1 and 50.

X2 <- X1 * 5 - 10  # creating linearly dependent series

X3 <- runif(100,1,50)


Y <- runif(1,-50,50) + runif(1,-5,5) * X1 +  runif(1,-5,5) * X2 + runif(1,-5,5) * X3 + runif(100,-10,10)


# To create dependency between Y and X variables, you should assign the coefficients. 
# Above, runif(1,-5,5) is standing for assigning random coefficients between -5 and 5.
# Finally runif(100,-10,10) is for creating the error terms.
```

To check the dependency, you can run a linear regression as,

```
summary(lm(Y~X1 + X2 + X3))
```

gives,

```
Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-9.7632 -4.2869 -0.4156  4.3876 10.3811 

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -65.74362    1.69357  -38.82   <2e-16 ***
X1           22.70622    0.04238  535.80   <2e-16 ***
X2                 NA         NA      NA       NA    
X3           -1.43227    0.04004  -35.77   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Since X1 and X2 are linearly dependent, R removes one of the variables which is X2 in this case.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know about `runif`. And does it grant that this model follows normal distribution?

Comment: `runif` gives you a uniform distribution. You can do the same with `rnorm` as well. And If you have a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228/proof-that-the-sum-of-two-gaussian-variables-is-another-gaussian) question, you can find the answer of your question about the normality.

Comment: Thank you, very explanatory answer